# How to store a string value in mongo db as an json object?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am getting the data from the UI as follows, all the below input data are strings.

cust_id : temp001
cust_chart_id : testing
default_chart : false
chart_pref_json : {range:6m,chart_type:candlestick,indicators:{},period:Daily,futurepadding:20} }

I am trying to store chart_pref_json in mongodb. This chart_pref_json object is actually stored in db as a string below,

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50aca4caf5d0b0e4d31ef239"), "cust_id" : "temp001", "cust_chart_id" : "testing", "default_chart" : "false", "created_at" : NumberLong("1353491658551"), **"chart_pref_json" : "{range:6m,chart_type:candlestick,indicators:{},period:Daily,futurepadding:20}" }**
```

But i actually want this chart_pref_json to be stored as an json object as below.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50aca4caf5d0b0e4d31ef239"), "cust_id" : "temp001", "cust_chart_id" : "testing", "default_chart" : "false", "created_at" : NumberLong("1353491658551"), **"chart_pref_json" : {range:6m,chart_type:candlestick,indicators:{},period:Daily,futurepadding:20} }**
```

Can any one help me out on this issue.

Comment: when i am trying to save "chart_pref_json" : {range:6m,chart_type:candlestick,indicators:{},period:Daily,futurepadding:20} } in mongodb , it is saved as string "{range:6m,chart_type:candlestick,indicators:{},period:Daily,futurepadding:20}"  instead i want to store as json {range:6m,chart_type:candlestick,indicators:{},period:Daily,futurepadding:20} without "".

Comment: Wanted and unwanted results look identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the JSON code as a string, you first have to parse the JSON code and then convert the resulting JSON object to a BSON object.

You can use the class [com.mongodb.util.JSON](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html) which comes with MongoDB. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a Java question, here's how you insert a JSON by using the MongoDB Java driver:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://myuser:mypsw@localhost:27017/mydb");
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("mydb");
        String json =
                "{\n" +
                "    \"_id\" : \"MyId\",\n" +
                "    \"foo\" : \"bar\"\n" +
                "}";
        db.getCollection("mycoll").insertOne(Document.parse(json));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you set it as a field in your application, you need to use your language's JSON decoding abilities to encode it as an object. In PHP, you would do that like:

```
$db->collection->insert( array(
    'cust_id' => 'temp001',
    … your other fields …
    'chart_pref' => json_decode( $varContainingJson )
) );
```

For Java, the following example will help:

```
BasicDBObject obj = JSON.parse( varContainingJson );
```

Which is described at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/Y3KyG_ZSfJg